# hasOne field not showing in add form from CRUD

Tags: php, frameworks, atk4

I am trying to show a different fields from model in form and grid in CRUD. As I understood, when I use setModel() method for CRUD I need to set Model, second value should be array of fields from Model that I want to be shown in form and third value should be array of fields that i want to be shown in grid.

Well, my Model has 4 hasOne() fields and when I want 2 of them to be shown in form they just not there. My code is here:

Model:

```
<?php
class Model_Objekat extends Model_Table {
    public $table = 'objekat';

    function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->hasOne('Kategorija',null,'kategorija');
        $this->hasOne('Korisnik',null,'puno_ime');
        $this->hasOne('Mesto',null,'naziv_mesta');
        $this->hasOne('Tip',null,'tip');

        $this->addField('investitor');
        $this->addField('naziv');
        $this->addField('adresa');
        $this->addField('biro');
        $this->addField('datum') -> type('date');
        $this->addField('slika_situacije');
        $this->addField('tehnicki_opis') -> type('text');
        $this->addField('A_omotaca');
        $this->addField('sum_Hts');
        $this->addField('Htb');
        $this->addField('Ht');
        $this->addField('HtPrim');
        $this->addField('V_omotaca');
        $this->addField('faktor_oblika');
        $this->addField('udeo_transparentne_A_procentualno');
        $this->addField('HtPrim_ispunjeno') -> type('boolean');
        $this->addField('Hv');
        $this->addField('korisna_A');
        $this->addField('gh_nd');
        $this->addField('qh_nd_interm');
        $this->addField('projektant');
        $this->addField('Cm');
        $this->addField('Tau');
        $this->addField('ah');
        $this->addField('broj_dana_grejanja_nedeljno');
        $this->addField('broj_sati_grejanja_dnevno');
        $this->addField('hladnjaca') -> type('boolean');
        $this->addField('fh_hr');
        $this->addField('V_grejanog_prostora');
        $this->addField('fotografija_objekta');
        $this->addField('katastarska_parcela');
        $this->addField('izvodjac');
        $this->addField('godina_rekonstrukcije');
        $this->addField('automatska_regulacija') -> type('boolean');
        $this->addField('centralna_regulacija') -> type('boolean');
        $this->addField('lokalna_regulacija') -> type('boolean');
        $this->addField('dnevni_prekid');
        $this->addField('nedeljni_prekid');
        $this->addField('sezonski_prekid');
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<?php
class page_ing_opstiPodaci extends Page {
    function init() {
        parent::init();

        $tabs = $this->add('Tabs');

        $tab = $tabs -> addTab('Objekti');

        $formFields = array('tip','kategorija','investitor');

        $tab -> add('CRUD') -> setModel('Objekat',
            array('tip','kategorija','investitor','naziv','adresa','biro','projektant',
            'korisnik','datum','katastarska_parcela','izvodjac','godina_rekonstrukcije'),
            array('tip','kategorija','investitor','naziv','adresa','biro','projektant',
            'korisnik','datum','katastarska_parcela','izvodjac','godina_rekonstrukcije'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post URL where we can see that happening?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your mistake is with parameters of `hasOne` and more importantly with field names which you use in your setModel.

`function hasOne($model,$our_field=null,$display_field=null,$as_field=null)...`

So,

- `$model` is class name of model or model itself.
- `$our_field` is field name in you current model `Model_Objekat`, by default, table name of related model + "_id".
- `$display_field` is field name from related model which to show. By default it'll be $our_field without "_id" suffix, but if $our_field doesn't contain _id suffix, then it'll be $our_field + "_text" suffix.
- `$as_field` is field name in related model which will be used as dereferenced field (contain title field value of referenced model).

When you create hasOne field, it actually creates two fields. One field for ID value and other field as expression which contains title value from referenced model.

That's a bit of background, but and now to the real issue.

Real issue is with field names you use in your setModel. As I mentioned above - hasOne creates two fields and you need to use one of them in Grid (dereferenced title field) and another in Form (ID field itself).

So in your case you should define it in model like this:

`$this->hasOne(
    'Kategorija',      /* model name */
    'kategorija',      /* ID field name in this models table, default will be kategorija_id */
    'kat_title',/* name of title field, by default in this case it'll be kategorija_text */
    null
);`

and in CRUD use like this

`$crud->setModel('Objekat', array('kategorija'), array('kat_title'));`

because in Form you have to show ID field, but in Grid you need to show title field.

Maybe I have made some mistake in these field names, but it really looks like your issue is something about these lines.

You can also debug by dumping:

`var_dump(array_keys($model->elements));`

and see all actual names of models fields.